# Getting the qBittorrent embedded tracker functionality working

Tags: qbittorrent, torrent-tracker

I am using qBittorrent to set up a private torrent and using the embedded tracker to seed it. However like many users, I am having issues with the clients leeching the torrent.

The settings are as they should be:

- Enable embedded tracker
- Tracker URL http://{ip-address}/announce
- Port 9000
- Share public IP address with leechers
- Enable port forwarding for embedded tracker
- Allow multiple connections from same IP address

My router had the port 9000 forwarded to my machine and is verified with the YouGetSignal open port tester: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

I can see the leecher occasionally showing up as a peer before dropping off the list again, and from the leecher's end, they are in either Waiting or Force Downloading, with zero data transfer.

They can navigate to the tracker address in a browser, confirming they can connect to this tracker, but still the connection won't move data.

What on earth is going on?

**Edit: Update 11/03/2024**

I have a suspicion my ISP was interfering with this connection, making any attempt to use it impossible.